# javafx drag-and-drop default icons

Tags: javafx-2

i want to connect 2 shapes with line, while mouse is pressed.
As doc says I can not use pressed-dragged-release model to do that so drag-and-drop method should be used - everything looks ok, but how to disable default icons,which says drag-drop content is allowed to put on target? on mouseMove i draw line and i do not want these default icons.

I include simple program showing it - just run i try drag one circle to other.

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package onreleased;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
*
* @author mmk
*/
public class DaDIcons extends Application {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");


        final Label label = new Label("started");
        label.setLayoutY(100);

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Circle red = createCircle(40, 40, 30, Color.RED, label);
        Circle blue = createCircle(160, 40, 30, Color.BLUE, label);

        pane.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {

                System.out.println("foo");

            }
        });

        pane.getChildren().addAll(red, blue, label);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Circle createCircle(double x, double y, double r, final Color color, final Label statusLabel) {

        final Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, r);
        circle.setFill(color);

        circle.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                statusLabel.setText(color.toString() + " over");
                System.out.println("foo");
                if (event.getGestureSource() != circle) {


                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                }
            }
        });

        circle.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent arg0) {
                statusLabel.setText(color.toString() + " dropped");
            }
        });

        circle.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                circle.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
                Dragboard db = circle.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                /*
                * Put a string on a dragboard
                */
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString("foo");
                db.setContent(content);


                statusLabel.setText(color.toString() + " xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            }
        });

        circle.setOnDragEntered(null);

        return circle;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the `Cursor` at drag-n-drop actions.
On `circle.setOnDragDetected()` action set `circle.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);` and,
on `circle.setOnDragDropped()` action reverse it `circle.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);`.
Instead of showing cursor icons you can show an image at mouse coordinates while d-n-dropping.

Comment: So how did it not work? Is it throwing an exception? Disabling the cursor does not fit your needs? The answer needs more explanation?

Comment: There is no effect setting Cursor.NONE on every drag event - it still remains default. I found meanwhile http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-20326 so propably i use onMousePressed on parent Node and i will check child node were pressed/released ;/

Comment: Sorry, either the question is misleading or i misunderstood it. In my project i have also used the drag-n-dropping. The dashboard items were buttons with images, which were dropped into the dashboard grid. While dragging, the cursor is disabled and instead of it an image of dragged button is shown using the imageview. Hereby Curser.NONE may work on different usages and circumstances.